# Construction of Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Consider the system $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{dx}{dt}=-2x\\ 
\frac{dy}{dt}=-2y-2z^2\sin y\cos y\\ 
\frac{dz}{dt}=-2z(\sin y)^2
\end{matrix}\right.$$ I want to show that the equilibrium point is stable.

To do that I want to construct the Lyapunov function.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We are looking for the function $v(x,y,z)$ such that $v(x,y,z)>0$ and $v(x,y,z)=0$ iff $x=y=z=0$ and $\frac{dv}{dt}\leq 0$.

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=v_x(-2x)+v_y(-2y-2z^2\sin y \cos y)-2z(\sin y)^2v_z$$

I thought to take $v_x=x, v_y=y, v_z=z$ then we would have 
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-2x^2-2y^2-2yz^2\sin y \cos y-2z^2\sin^2 y$$

If we hadn't the term $2yz^2\sin \cos y$, we would have $\frac{dv}{dt}\leq 0$, right?

In this case we can't, can we?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a Lyapunov function.

Notice that the origin is stable for the first and third equations (for the third note that $(\sin y)^2>0$ in a neighborhood of zero, outside zero).

So, it remains to consider the second equation: if $z$ is small (and you know that then it will be bounded), then the right-hand side is approximately $-2y+z^22y=(-2+2z^2)y$, since $\sin y\cos y/y\to1$ when $y\to0$.

Comment: Ah ok... And if we would do that with a Lyapunov function? What could we do then? Is my approach correct so far?

Comment: Your's is in fact a Lyapunov function. But I only see how to show that (more precisely to deal with the second component) using my approach. But then you don't need anymore a Lyapunov function, in case the objective is only showing stability.

Comment: Concerning the Lyapunov function, for which $(x,y,z)$ should it stand that $\frac{dv}{dt}\leq 0$ ? For all the $(x,y,z)$ of the domain?

Comment: No, only in a neighborhood (in this case in the best possible coming from $z$).

Comment: Why should it come from $z$ ?